# Has many :through a Polymorphic association not aliasing type column with Squeel 1.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, polymorphism, squeel

I've got a few classes:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :member, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, as: :member, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end

class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, as: :member, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end
```

and

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :member
  has_many :packages, through: :memberships, source: :member, source_type: 'Package'
  has_many :users, through: :memberships, source: :member, source_type: 'User'
end
```

A Users and Packages can have membership in a Group. All of this appears to be ok until I try to get the Users that belong to a Group. In the console, with an instance of a Group g:

```
[5] pry(main)> g.users
  User Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "USERS".* FROM "USERS" INNER JOIN "MEMBERSHIPS" ON 
"USERS"."ID" = "MEMBERSHIPS"."MEMBER_ID" WHERE "MEMBERSHIPS"."GROUP_ID" = :a1 AND
"USERS"."MEMBER_TYPE" = 'User'  [["group_id", 10000]]
OCIError: ORA-00904: "USERS"."MEMBER_TYPE": invalid identifier: 
  SELECT "USERS".* 
  FROM "USERS" 
    INNER JOIN "MEMBERSHIPS" ON "USERS"."ID" = "MEMBERSHIPS"."MEMBER_ID" 
  WHERE "MEMBERSHIPS"."GROUP_ID" = :a1 
    AND "USERS"."MEMBER_TYPE" = 'User'
```

It's easy to see the error - the Users table doesn't have the Member_Type column, it resides on the Membership table.

Why is the column not being aliased appropriately? Anyone else having this problem?

**Update**

This is an issue with Squeel - removing it from my Gemfile and the association behaves properly.

Logged an issue - https://github.com/ernie/squeel/issues/288

Comment: Its working fine. I think there is some problem with your migration. i just tried with your code. coould you share you migration?

Comment: @raysrashmi I've updated my question with the polymorphic migration and the schema. I'm starting to believe that this is an issue with the oracle_enhanced-adapter :(

Comment: If your tests are failing, you need to migrate your test db as well.  Use `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: Not an issue with oracle_enhanced-adapter (apologies), but rather a bug in Squeel. Remove the gem and association works appropriately.